# C# Разгадываниe текста по картинке

Tags: c#, распознавание-символов

У меня есть картинка с текстом написанным необычным шрифтом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также я знаю и [сам шрифт](https://www.fonts-online.ru/font/HACKED)

Какой самый простой способ распознать этот текст?

Comment: Тут, наверное, можно разбить картину по буквам и сопоставить картинку буквы с буквой. Вроде бы все буквы нарисованы пиксель к пикселю и буквы не налезают друг на друга. Подобное делал для разгадывания простых капчей и номеров телефонов: [1](https://github.com/gil9red/parser-phone-image), [2](https://github.com/gil9red/ads_sites_parser/tree/master/avito_ru_phone_parser), [3](https://github.com/gil9red/parsing_captcha), [4](https://github.com/gil9red/parsing-captcha-2), [5](https://github.com/gil9red/parsing-captcha-3)

Comment: Самый простой способ... обход слевонаправо - сверху вниз сравнение с каждым шаблоном с сбором статистики попаданий когда разность цветов - 5-10 едениц. Потом берём тот шаблон который набрал макс статистику там... более 90% например. Если менее - сдвигаем на пиксель вправо и повторяем. Самый медленный способ - но самый простой.